# Cuando usar new en declaracion de punteros y cuando this

Tags: c++

A la hora de declarar punteros yo siempre he utilizado la siguiente forma:

```
int *edad = &numero;
```

Pero no hago más que ver en muchos sitios como, al declarar un puntero, usan algo parecido a:

```
int *edad = new int;
```

¿Qué diferencia hay entre las dos formas?

Y la segunda cuestión es: ¿Cuando se usa this y por/para qué?

Edito:

He encontrado una posible utilidad, y es preguntar al usuario la cantidad de datos a almacenar, para asi reservar la memoria en funcion de los datos a ingresar. Algo asi:

```
cout << "Cuantos nombres quieres introducir?: ";
int t;
cin >> t; 
cin.ignore();
string *nombre = new string[t];

for(int i=0; i!=t; i++){
    cout << "Escribe un nombre: ";
    getline(cin, nombre[i]);
    cout << endl;
}

cout << endl << endl;
for(int i=0; i!=t; i++){
    cout << i+1 << ": " << nombre[i] << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> ¿Qué diferencia hay entre las dos formas?

Un puntero es una variable especial que, en vez de almacenar valores, almacena posiciones de memoria... es decir, apunta a otros elementos.

Así, el siguiente código:

```
int variable;
int* ptr = &variable;
```

lo que hace es que el puntero apunte a una variable concreta... si modificas la variable, el valor al que apunta el puntero también cambiará y viceversa.

En cambio, el siguiente código:

```
int* ptr = new int;
```

Lo que hace es, por un lado, realizar una reserva de memoria dinámica y, seguidamente, modifica el puntero para que apunte a dicha memoria.

¿Qué implicaciones tiene un uso y cuales el otro?

- Las variables tienen un ámbito determinado. Fuera de ese ámbito la variable, simplemente, no existe y todo puntero que apunte a la variable pasará a ser no válido (leerá basura y escribirá memoria que no debería):

  ```
  int* func()
  {
    int var;
    int* ptr = &var;

    *ptr = 5; // ok
    return ptr;
  }

  int main()
  {
    int* ptr = func();

    *ptr = 10; // peligro!!! ptr apunta a var que ya no existe
  }
  ```
- La memoria dinámica no tiene un ciclo de vida definido sino que es el propio algoritmo el que debe liberar la memoria cuando ya no sea necesaria. Además, la memoria dinámica suele ser mucho más abundante que la memoria de la pila:

  ```
  int* func()
  {
    int* ptr = new int;
    *ptr = 5; // ok
    return ptr;
  }

  int main()
  {
    int* ptr = func();
    *ptr = 10; // ok
    delete ptr;
  }
  ```

> ¿Cuando se usa this y por/para qué?

`this` es un puntero implícito que únicamente existe dentro de las clases y estructuras. Cuando tu escribes un código como este:

```
struct Test
{
  int var;

  void func()
  { var = 5; }
};
```

El compilador lo interpreta así:

```
struct Test
{
  int var;

  void func()
  { this->var = 5; }
};
```

Pero ¿cuándo hay que usar `this`?

Es necesario usar `this` en aquellas situaciones en las que se producen solapamiento de nombres. Por ejemplo, en el siguiente código:

```
struct Test
{
  int var;

  void func(int var)
  {
    var = 5;
  }
};
```

¿Qué variable estamos modificando? ¿la variable miembro de la estructura? ¿La variable local de la función?

La respuesta es: la variable local de la función.

¿Y cómo se podría acceder a la variable miembro? En este caso es cuando tenemos que usar `this` obligatoriamente:

```
struct Test
{
  int var;

  void func(int var)
  {
    this->var = var;
  }
};
```

En el resto de situaciones no es obligatorio su uso. Así pues queda relegado a gustos del programador, reglas de codificación, ...

Answer (score 2):

En ambos casos estás creando un objeto o variable y una referencia al mismo.

Creación del objeto:

En el primer caso (**int** *variable*) el objeto se crea de forma estática y se almacena en la pila y en el segundo (**new int**) se crea dinámicamente y se guarda en el heap. La creación estática implica que el objeto (la memoria que ocupa) se libera cuando finaliza el ámbito donde se ha creado. En cambio, si el objeto se crea dinámicamente ocupará memoria hasta que se elimine de forma explícita mediante el operador **delete**.

Referencia al objeto:

En el primer caso (**int*** *ptr* = **&** *variable*) se crea una variable estáticamente (*ptr*) que guardará la dirección donde se encuentra el objeto creado.

En el segundo, se crea la misma variable estáticamente a la que se asigna el resultado del operador **new**, que no es más que la dirección del objeto creado.

Por tanto, en ambos casos la variable *ptr* contiene una referencia al objeto creado (la dirección de la memoria que ocupa) y la diferencia fundamental entre ambas formas es el ámbito desde el que puede accederse. Un objeto creado de forma dinámica puede ser accedido desde otros ámbitos diferentes al que se ha creado.

Este comportamiento implica que las variables *ptr* que contienen la referencia al objeto y que se han creado en ambos casos estáticamente, dejarán de existir cuando finalice el ámbito en el que se han declarado, quedando ambos objetos *variable* sin ninguna referencia que los haga accesible. Esto no es un problema en el primer caso ya que el objeto también será destruido porque se creo estáticamente pero en el segundo caso el objeto quedará ocupando memoria inaccesible hasta que finalice el proceso y se liberen todos los recursos asociados.

Comment: Está mal expresado. Las variables *ptr* que contienen la referencia al objeto no dejan de existir... apunta a algo válido, pero esos punteros siguen existiendo